# Regular expression with OR operator

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I have a matcher with the regular expresion `\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d | \\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d` because I) want it to verify either something like `1.1.0.0` or `1.1.0` exists. However it keeps throwing `"Illegal State Exception: No match found"`

I know it's because my RegEx is not ok, but after reading examples and documentation, I don't know what's wrong.

EDITED: This is the portion of the code that is not working.

```
Matcher versionPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d | \\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d").matcher(name);

        if(versionPattern.find()){
            int i = 0;  boolean found= false;

            while ( i < listOfExistingFiles.length && !found){
                if(listOfExistingFiles[i].getName().contains(versionPattern.group().toString())){
                    found = true;
                    System.out.println("Running  " + listOfExistingFiles[i].toString());
                    runSqlScriptFrom(listOfExistingFiles[i].toString());
                }
                i++;
            }
            if(!found)
                System.out.println("Could not find the corresponding file. Assuming it is not required." );
        }
```

And this is the exact part that I don't know how to handle `versionPattern.find()` is throwing `false` the whole time.

Comment: [Your regex is cool](https://regex101.com/r/iM3gG9/1) :) Just run the matcher.

Comment: Show us your code which will let us reproduce this problem. Also remember that space surrounding `|` is also included in regex so `| \\d...` represents `OR[space][digit]...`

Comment: Just added some detail to the question :)

Comment: Changed the Regex to `(\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d|\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d)` and now it's working just fine. The Regex tester was really helpful.